# How to load Spring boot application static contain automatically while server is running?

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application in which at location src/resource/static I have kept my all html, js and css files, Whenever I do any changes in these files I need to restart the spring boot application. Is there any easy way so that I will not require to restart my application.

Comment: As per the spring boot documentation, you need to move the static contents to webapps folder.Try doing this .Also make  your Project settings to Build automatically if you using eclipse

Comment: i don't think you need to restart the spring boot application

Comment: Restart is not required if he moves his static contents to webapps.Please refer my answer below

Comment: I tried this but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the spring boot documentation, you need to move the static contents under  web apps folder. Also make following settings

> Projects->Build automatically

if you using eclipse

1) If you are using thyme leaf it would be very easy just add

> spring.resources.static-locations

in application properties.

2) If you want auto restart try adding

> spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths

to your

> application.properties

References :

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-live-reload/
http://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-automatic-restart-using-developer-tools-with-maven

Using Thymeleaf:

http://blog.codeleak.pl/2016/12/thymeleaf-reload-templates-and-static-resources.html

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, for the response this property in application.property helped me to solve the issue spring.devtools.remote.restart.enabled=false

Comment: Glad you are able to resolve the issue .You are welcome.